# Error while loading #temp table from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 12 of these types of procedures and 11 of them work flawlessly. but 1 of them errors out showing me a Column not found: the number of columns match up and in the other 11 procedures the column names don't match yet still run without issue.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Temp_Table
FROM dbo.Physical_Table
WHERE 1 = 2  

INSERT INTO #Temp_Table
    EXEC [DATABASE].DBO.[Stored_Procedure]
```

If I specify the column names like so

```
SELECT Physical_table.[Column_1] as [Column_1] <-- name of column returned in procedure
      ,Physical_table.[Column_2] as [Column_2] <-- name of column returned in procedure
      ,Physical_table.[Column_3] as [Column_3] <-- name of column returned in procedure
      .
      .
      ...
INTO #Temp_Table
FROM dbo.Physical_Table
WHERE 1 = 2  

INSERT INTO #Temp_Table
    EXEC [DATABASE].DBO.[Stored_Procedure]
```

It runs without issue, but this is only one procedure that's doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the schema of `dbo.PhysicalTable`, and what is the output of `dbo.StoredProcedure`? It's pretty obvious that the table has at least one more column than the procedure result set.

Comment: Try running it without insert, count columns.

Comment: The dbo.PhysicalTable and the output from dbo.StoredProcedure are both the same number of columns and data types, dbo.PhysicalTable was originally modeled off the output from dbo.StoredProcedure. the only difference in the column names.

Comment: No one can debug code that cannot be seen nor correct an error for which no useful information is supplied. The fact that you have "similar" logic that does work is simply not relevant here. Without a code sample and the complete error message (all of it, not just the text), there is little anyone can do but guess. At the very LEAST you could have mentioned that there are 94 columns.